# Self Referencing table : UNIQUE constraint failed (SQL)

Tags: sql, database-design, sqlite

## Architecture

I have the following self referencing table. Every Entity has a relation with 1 to many entities.

[image]

### Tables

Since it's a 1 to many relationship I representation `Relation` by a table.

```
CREATE TABLE ENTITY (ID TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, VALUE TEXT);
CREATE TABLE RELATION (ID_SOURCE TEXT NOT NULL, ID_DESTINATION TEXT NOT NULL, PREDICAT TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(ID_SOURCE, ID_DESTINATION), FOREIGN KEY(ID_SOURCE) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID), FOREIGN KEY(ID_DESTINATION) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID));
```

## Problem

When I am inserting the values I am getting the following error:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: RELATION_ENTITY.ID,
>   RELATION_ENTITY.ID_DESTINATION

I know why I am getting this error. I am inserting the same Ids in the table `Relation` But the value is different. THE entity `m.06y3r` references the entity `m.02jvmvm` with two different values. How can I fix this design error?

```
ID_SOURCE    ID_DESTINATION          VALUE
 m.06y3r       m.02jvmvm        adopted_child.adoptive
 m.06y3r       m.02jvmvm        people.person.parents
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all because in `Relation` table you have `PRIMARY KEY(ID_SOURCE, ID_DESTINATION)` so this both values have to create unique set. If you change it to `PRIMARY KEY(ID_SOURCE, ID_DESTINATION, VALUE)`, then it should work just fine.

EDIT

example of solution mentioned in comment below:

```
CREATE TABLE RELATION (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    ID_SOURCE TEXT NOT NULL,
    ID_DESTINATION TEXT NOT NULL,
    VALUE TEXT,

    PRIMARY KEY(ID), 
    UNIQUE (ID_SOURCE, ID_DESTINATION, VALUE)
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_SOURCE) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID_DESTINATION) REFERENCES ENTITE(ID));
```

Comment: well it is quite common, however other solution is to create `PRIMARY KEY (ID)` in table `Relation` and add `UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS` on set `(ID_SOURCE, ID_DESTINATION, VALUE)` with in my opinion is better solution.

Comment: one last question please adding a Primaryt key to table Relation. Wont that be an error because it's a 1 to many relation. So relation is playing the role of  a **Junction table **.

Comment: it is a bit offroad, however i've seen this quite a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want rows with duplicate values for *id_source* and *id_destination* you can either use a surrogate primary key (like an autonumber int), maybe `id_relation`, together with a unique constraint for the three other columns or extend the primary key to include the value column too so that it would be *PRIMARY KEY(ID_SOURCE, ID_DESTINATION, VALUE)*.

If you want to reference this table in joins, using a surrogate key might make your life easier.

Comment: So @jpw Relation will become a table right? I mean there will be a:
**Entity  1 ---> M Relation**  then **Relation 1 ---> M Entity** and Of course i'll add an integer ID KEY to relation

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. The only changes I propose is to add the id column and a unique constraint for the three remaining columns.

Comment: even If table Relation is a junction table right? Sorry asking these question just to be sure.